# Получаю ошибку ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python

```
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv
txt = open(filename)
print(f"Содержимое файла {filename}:")
print(txt.read())
print("Снова введите имя файла:")
file_again = input("> ")
txt_again = open(file_again)
print(txt_again.read())
```

Comment: Может argv() надо писать?

Comment: Сейчас вы просто ссылку на функцию пытаетесь распаковать в две переменных

Answer (score 0):

Ну, что же давайте разберем.

Документация по `argv` можно найти на [сайте с документацией](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html). Другими словами `argv` будет содержать аргументы командной строки.

Проубем запустить ваш код с одним лишь добавлением строки вывода с содержанием самого `argv`

```py
from sys import argv
print(argv) # здесь смотрим, что содержит argv
script, filename = argv
txt = open(filename)
print(f"Содержимое файла {filename}:")
print(txt.read())
print("Снова введите имя файла:")
file_again = input("> ")
txt_again = open(file_again)
print(txt_again.read())
```

вызов

```py
C:\...> py t.py
```

вывод ожидаемо (файл `t.py` у меня)

```py
['t.py']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\t.py", line 3, in <module>
    script, filename = argv
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Ошибка говорит, что у вас не достаточно аргументнов передано из командной строки. Т.е. ожидается 2, но получено всего лишь 1. Это можно увидеть в выводе содержания `argv`. А теперь передадим при запуске файла `t.py` дополнительный аргумент, который ожидается распаковкой `script, filename = argv`.

Ну так давайте передадим дополнительный аргумент. Вызов:

```py
py t.py t.py
```

Вывод

```py
C:\...>py t.py t.py
['t.py', 't.py']
Содержимое файла t.py:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:...\t.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(txt.read())
  File "C:...cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 194: character maps to <undefined>
```

Работа уже дошла до строки, которая содержит `print(txt.read())`. Это не мое дело, поэтому просто закомментирую ее и запущу по новой:

```py
C:\...>py t.py t.py
['t.py', 't.py']
Содержимое файла t.py:
Снова введите имя файла:
>
```

Результат, который вы ожидаете, наверное.

PS: я абослютно не вдавался в логику ваших действий. Я скорее показал метод, как поправить некорректное поведение.

UPD

если не игнорировать ошибку кодировки, то конечное решение:

```py
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv
txt = open(filename,  encoding="utf8")
print(f"Содержимое файла {filename}:")
print(txt.read())
print("Снова введите имя файла:")
file_again = input("> ")
txt_again = open(file_again, encoding="utf8")
print(txt_again.read())
```

Вызов:

```py
C:\...>py t.py test_read.txt
```

Вывод:

```py
Содержимое файла test_read.txt:
line 1
line 2
here is line 3
Снова введите имя файла:
>
```